# How to build Qt 5.7.0 for cross compilation?

Tags: c++, linux, qt5, cross-compiling

How to build Qt 5.7.0 on Ubuntu for cross compile to Windows?

I have this error:

```
In file included from qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0/qtbase/include/QtCore/qt_windows.h:1:0,
             from main.cpp:33:
qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0/qtbase/include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/global/qt_windows.h:61:21: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
```

My configure options:

```
./configure -opensource -c++std c++11 -xplatform win32-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=i686-w64-mingw32- -device-option PKG_CONFIG=i686-w64-mingw32-pkg-config -force-pkg-config -prefix /opt/qt/qt-5.7.0-win32 -nomake examples
```

windows.h has path: /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h

Note: I don't want to use MXE.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the proper fix, but it seems Qt tries to build one of the tools under ActiveQt (which is Windows-Only) as native.

Here I edited this file:

**qtactiveqt/src/tools/idc/idc.pro**

And commented out the two first lines, this seemed to fix the issue.

(I also do have binfmt configured to run .exe files through wine, this may influence if it tries to run the idc tool as a native tool)